# how to get the substring in yii

Tags: php, yii, substring, textfield

```
    <tr style="display:none">       
  <td><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'classcode'); ?></td>
        <td>    
            <?php echo $form->textField($model,'classcode',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>100,'id'=>'new-base-ref-si-classification-classcode','disabled'=>'')); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,'classcode'); ?>

        </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Classification'); ?></td>
        <td>    
            <?php echo $form->textField($model,'Classification',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>100,'id'=>'new-base-ref-si-classification-Classification','disabled'=>'')); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,'Classification'); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

i am having a hard time figuring out what to do please help me .. what i need to is the classcode is hidden .. when i enter a a string it a code will get the first letter and then it will be entered on the classcode before hitting the submit button

for example
i entered Office supplies on the classification textfield
the code will get O and S then it will be entered on classcode texfield before submittion

Answer (score 0):

Since this field is not displayed and will not recieve user input at all you dont need it in the view file.

Best approach is to set classcode to unsafe so that it could not be massively assigned

and then it is calculated in server side after submit in your model:

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        // ... snip ... other rules here
        array('classcode', 'unsafe'), // will not be massively assigned, prevents hacks
        array('Classification', 'filterClasscode'), // custom validator
    );
}

/**
 * Custom filter to set classcode
 * @param string $attribute field to set classcode from
 */    
public function filterClasscode($attribute)
{
    $this->classcode = '';
    foreach (explode(' ', $this->$attribute) as $val) {
        $this->classcode .= substr($val, 0, 1);
    }

    $this->classcode = strtoupper($this->classcode);
}
```

Comment: it works very well thank you for your help although i have to change => to as to work but this is really good thanks .